# How to get value from XML tag in Python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I have an XML file, I need to extract all text inside the feature tag in Python

```
<person>
    <text id="1">
    <title>
      student
    </title>
    <feature>
       xxxx
      <name>yyyy</name>
      zzzz
      <country>dddd</country>
      ffff
    </feature>
```

my code is this:

```
 for person in tree.iter():
    for text in person:
        for feature in text:
            if feature.tag=="feature":
                print(feature.text)
```

It just shows me the "xxxx" but my ideal answer is
xxxx yyyy zzzz dddd ffff

Comment: It is very unusual to have a XML node contain both text contents and other XML nodes like that.  Possibly why you are having an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Of course there's a line missing at the end (`</person>`). and you should comment which library you are using, if any

If you use a library to 'parse' the xml into a tree structure, say `xml.etree.ElementTree`, you fairly easily extract tags, attributes and even text by the query functions of the library. You can do so in the order you want, and create a result in you desired format.

`xml.etree.ElementTree` is part the Python standard library. Have a look at the [Python ElementTree documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html?highlight=elementtree). There are plenty examples.